# Munkres, Lemma 16.2: Existence of $C_x$ s.t it is disjoint from $D_{i-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 137, it is given that

[image]

I have doubts about the existence of such a $C_x$, so just to make sure, I wanted the prove the existence of such a set $C_x$.

**Proof:**

Let assume that for some $x_0 \in B_i$, every neighbourhood $C_{x_0}$ of $x_0$ has a non-empty intersection with $D_{i-2}$. Then since $B_i \subseteq Ext(D_{i-2})$, and $C_{x_0} \cap B_i \not = \emptyset$, then it must be true that $$x_0 \in \partial D_{i-2} \subseteq D_{i-2},$$
but $B_i$ and $D_{i-2}$ are disjoint, a contradiction.

---

Is there any flaw in the proof ? I'm particularly asking this because it took me 1 day to figure out this contradiction out clearly.

Comment: This is fine as an indirect proof.  Directly $B_i = D_i - \text{Int }D_{i-1}$ and $D_{i-2} \subset \text{Int } D_{i-1}$ implies $B_i \subset \text{Ext } D_{i-2}$ as you observed.  There is an open ball and, hence, a cube containing $x_0$ that does not meet $D_{i-2}$ by definition of exterior.

Comment: @RRL Oh, you are right. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @onurcanbektas I pointed it out also

Comment: @mathworker21 Well, actually I did not understand what you mean by "there is a distance between disjoint compact sets", and I was distracted by some other thing before writing this as a comment. Thank you for your answer also; it was my mistake that I couldn't ask for further clarification about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel like reading your proof, but here's the proof that comes to my mind. $B_i$ and $D_{i-2}$ are disjoint compact sets, so they are some positive distance apart from each other. So given any $x \in B_i$, we can take a small enough cube centered at $x$ that is disjoint from $D_{i-2}$ (we can insist the cube is contained in $A$, since $A$ is open).

Comment: If the question posed is whether a proposed proof is valid, answers starting with "I didn't feel like reading your proof" are at best vacuous.

Comment: Because onurcanbektas said "I'm particularly asking this because it took me 1 day to figure out this contradiction out clearly.", I thought my answer would be of use to him. There are many times on stack exchange when people don't directly answer a question but instead provide something useful to the questioner. I would like if you removed the downvote or explained it further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your proof is correct.

> **Proof:**
>
> Let assume that for some $x_0 \in B_i$, every neighbourhood $C_{x_0}$ of $x_0$ has a non-empty intersection with $D_{i-2}$. Then since $B_i \subseteq Ext(D_{i-2})$, and $C_{x_0} \cap B_i \not = \emptyset$, then it must be true that $$x_0 \in \partial D_{i-2} \subseteq D_{i-2},$$
> but $B_i$ and $D_{i-2}$ are disjoint, a contradiction.

I understood your proof as follows:

> Assume that there exists $x_0\in B_i$ such that every closed cube $C_{x_0}$ centerd at $x_0$ is not disjoint from $D_{i-2}$.
> Since $D_{i-2}\subset\operatorname{Int}D_{i-1}$, $\mathbb{R}^n-\operatorname{Int}D_{i-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^n-D_{i-2}.$
> And $B_i\subset\mathbb{R}^n-\operatorname{Int}D_{i-1}.$
> So, $B_i\subset\mathbb{R}^n-D_{i-2}.$
> $\mathbb{R}^n-D_{i-2}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> So, $\mathbb{R}^n-D_{i-2}=\operatorname{Ext}D_{i-2}.$
> Therefore, $B_i\subset\operatorname{Ext}D_{i-2}.$
>
> Let $C_{x_0}$ be an aribitrary closed cube centerd at $x_0$.
> Since $x_0\in C_{x_0}\cap B_i$, $C_{x_0}\cap B_i\neq\emptyset.$
> And $C_{x_0}\cap B_i\subset C_{x_0}\cap\operatorname{Ext}D_{i-2}.$
> So, $C_{x_0}\cap\operatorname{Ext}D_{i-2}\neq\emptyset.$
> So, $C_{x_0}\cap (\mathbb{R}^n-D_{i-2})\neq\emptyset$ since $\mathbb{R}^n-D_{i-2}=\operatorname{Ext}D_{i-2}.$
>
> By our assumption, $C_{x_0}\cap D_{i-2}\neq\emptyset.$
>
> So, $x_0\in\operatorname{Bd}D_{i-2}$ by the definition of the boundary of a set.
> Since $D_{i-2}$ is an closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\operatorname{Bd}D_{i-2}\subset D_{i-2}$.
> So, $x_0\in D_{i-2}.$
>
> So, $x_0\in B_i\cap D_{i-2}.$
> Since $B_i\subset\operatorname{Ext}D_{i-2}$, this is a contradiction.